# How compress functions in atom editor?

Tags: shortcut, atom-editor

I have using Atom Editor for a while and I don't find the way to compress all functions in a file.
When I open a file with twenty or thirty functions, I need see only the headers and I have to lose a lot of time clicking in simbol near to head function to compress all.
I think that exist a shortcut to do this but I can't find it.
Someone know it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to `Edit > Folding`.
There you will find different actions (fold, fold all, unfold, unfold all), with the corresponding keybindings.

Comment: Hotkey Mac Cmd + Opt + Shift + [

Answer (score 4):

on Mac OS you can use hot key:

```
Cmd + Option + shift + [
```

Answer (score -1):

In windows

`ctrl + ALT + [` To Open

`crtl + ALT + ]`  To Close